# Converting array using reduce

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0] into [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0] using the reduce method but I', not very successful.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. All array elements that are zero should be converted to the sum of the predecessors in the original array and the current element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: It's not clear how to "point you" without just doing it. Would a link to the documentation help?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use `reduce` rather than a simple for/loop?

Comment: Your desired result doesn't seem to match your description. The third element of the original array is zero, but it's not converted to 1.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6]`?

Comment: No, the result is correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you go:

```js
const original = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
const arr = original.slice() // copy the original array to not mutate it

arr.reduce((sum, item, idx) => item ? arr[idx] = sum += item : sum, 0)
  
console.log(arr)
```

If you want to go cranky - reduce with returning the result array:

```js
const original = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

const arr = original.reduce(({sum, arr}, item) => (arr.push(item ? sum += item : 0), {sum, arr}), {sum: 0, arr: []}).arr;
  
console.log('original array: ', original.join())
console.log('reduced result: ', arr.join())
```

The author asked also to map `["a", ["a", "b"], "c", ["d", "e"], "d", "e", ["c", "d"], "g"]` so some tweaks:

```js
const original = ["a", ["a", "b"], "c", ["d", "e"], "d", "e", ["c", "d"], "g"];

const arr = original.reduce(
  (arr, item) => arr.push(Array.isArray(item) ? arr.sum = (arr.sum || 0) + 1 : 0) && arr, []
)

console.log('reduced result: ', arr.join())
```

Benchmark all solution with the updated data:

```html
<script name="benchmark" data-count="10000000">

// @benchmark copy and reduce
const original = ["a", ["a", "b"], "c", ["d", "e"], "d", "e", ["c", "d"], "g"]
const arr = original.map(item => Number(Array.isArray(item))) // copy the original array to not mutate it
arr.reduce((sum, item, idx) => item ? arr[idx] = sum += item : sum, 0)
arr

// @benchmark reduce only
const reduced = ["a", ["a", "b"], "c", ["d", "e"], "d", "e", ["c", "d"], "g"].reduce(
  (arr, item) => arr.push(Array.isArray(item) ? arr.sum = (arr.sum || 0) + 1 : 0) && arr, []
)
reduced

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use reduce to create a new array with the same result but keeping the original array unchanged?

Comment: @N1c0 you can copy the source array with `slice()`. secondly i've added 1 more solution where you fill a new array right inside `reduce()`

Comment: Thank you @alexander-nenashev, really appreciate your help. The "original" array is actually not the starting point. The starting point is an array where the array elements are a mix of strings and arrays of strings (i.e. ["a", ["a", "b"], "c", ["d", "e"], "d", "e", ["c", "d"], "g"] and I need to get from there to [0,1,0,2,0,0,3,0]. So I started with original.map(map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? 1 : 0).reduce....
Is there a solution to get this done this way?

Comment: @N1c0 added benchmarks and seems that the mapping and reduce is twice faster than the reduce only!

Comment: Nice find. I will use the combination of mapping and reduce. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.